Eclipse and Japa
There are many references which says japa is very effective during eclipse.
Question is, does the japa has to be done in the place where it is visible. Suppose eclipse can be seen in Antarctica but the person doing japa in Russia. Is it effective in Russia as well ? Or it’s effective only in Antarctica.

Only where eclipse is visible ..in other places eclipse related rules or restrictions are not valid

Thanks @Rickross for clarifying.

@Rickross, one follow up question, is effectiveness of any sadhana is dependent on degree of eclipse?

No I don't think so .. never read anything like that so far.
